# For how many parts is the house divided to? (the structure of this question)

Tags: prepositions, questions, sentence-structure

As a part of the English learning I am trying to build sentences - naturally, but sometimes I have a sentences that I'm not sure if they're correct and if a native English speaker would use them by himself or what is the better alternatives for them. One of those interrogative sentences that I build today is

> **For** how many parts is the house divided **to**?

My doubts are: if it's correct to open a interrogative question with the prepositional "for", at least in this case. If it's correct to end with the preposition "to" in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.  Let's break this down...

**Is it correct to open a interrogative question with the prepositional "for"?**

The answer in general is **yes, that's fine**.  "For whom did you buy the flowers?" or "For how long did you live in Venice?" are perfectly normal. But...

**Is it correct to open a interrogative question with the prepositional "for"  *in this case?***

In this case, **no**.  [You divide something *into* parts, not *for* parts, or *for to* parts.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/divide)  So the correct phrasing would be 
**"Into how many parts is the house divided?"**  Another, more conversational and less formal way to phrase it would be **"How many parts is the house divided into?"**